# I exit() a script but it does NOT exit

Tags: python

I try to exit a script but it doesn't exit.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

try:
    ...
    print "I'm gonna die!"
    sys.exit()
except:
    ...

print 'Still alive!'
```

And the results are:

```
I'm gonna die!
Still alive!
```

WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* need to exit immediately, and want to skip normal exit processing, then you can use [`os._exit(status)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit).  But, as others have said, it's generally much better to exit using the normal path, and just not catch the `SystemExit` exception.  And while we're on the topic, `KeyboardInterrupt` is another exception that you may not want to catch.  (Using `except Exception` will not catch either `SystemExit` or `KeyboardInterrupt`.)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I really need in this case.

Answer (score 23):

You are catching the `SystemExit` exception with your blanket `except` clause. Don't do that. Always specify what exceptions you are expecting to avoid exactly these things.

Comment: In this case `except Exception` would be enough as `SystemExit` doesn't inherit from that...

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exit()` is implemented by raising the `SystemExit` exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally, except clauses of try statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.

In your example `SystemExit` is catched by the following `except` statement.